# How to store 100 iPad CGImages in NSDictonary iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cgimage

I have 100 iPad image, want to store them in dictonary...if i stored them in my NSMutable dictionary app is crashing..

Example Code is:

```
NSMutableDictionary *workingDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[_assets count]];
[workingDictionary setObject:@"JPEG" forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"];
[workingDictionary setObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
[workingDictionary setObject:[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] valueForKey:[[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
```

Comment: If you're trying to store 100 full screen images in an array, that's not going to work. You'll be out of memory very quickly. Write your images to disk and only load the ones you actually need.

Comment: @DrummerB thanks for your reply... this code is from ELCImagePickerController...i.e. selection of multiple images at a time...can you please let me know how can i modify this

Comment: You should modify it to only load the ones you actually need, as @DrummerB said.